# Is there a name for a composite number which contains a factor as a substring?

Tags: number-theory

For example, the number 2231 has factors 23 and 97, and 23 is a substring of 2231. Is there a name for this type of number?

Comment: You can try and plug the first several numbers of this type into [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) and see what you get. I would guess you'll come up with nothing because factors are significant to a number independent of what base it is written in but these substrings are relative to base.

Comment: Any positive integer is a factor and a substring of itself.  Do you mean proper factor?

Comment: There are some related oeis. https://oeis.org/A002796. In general, we don't have names for every sequence because there are many sequences of interest.

Comment: See also [A038770](https://oeis.org/A038770).